# electron node-loudness - executable not found after release

Tags: electron, electron-builder

I'm trying to build a app using `Quasar Framework` and I'm deploying to Windows with the help of the `ElectronJS`.

One of the requisites of the application, the app will be able to control the device's volume, and for that task I'm using `node-loudness` package.

that feature works as expected while on development mode, but fails after got builded to production. I'm building the app using `electron-builder` with `asar: true` and the package `node-loudness` is already unpacked in the process.

Whorever the app is looking for `adjust_get_current_system_volume_vista_plus.exe` in the whong place, as u can see in the follow stack.:

```
Error: spawn %LocalAppData%\Programs\app.name\resources\app.asar\adjust_get_current_system_volume_vista_plus.exe ENOENT
    at i (file:///%LocalAppData%\Programs\app.name/resources/app.asar/js/vendor.js:8:117490)
    at a (file:///%LocalAppData%\Programs\app.name/resources/app.asar/js/vendor.js:8:117825)
    at ChildProcess.e.emit (file:///%LocalAppData%\Programs\app.name/resources/app.asar/js/vendor.js:8:117708)
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:198:12)"
```

but that file got unpacked while building and can be found at the follow location `%LocalAppData%\Programs\app.name\resources\app.asar.unpacked\node_modules\loudness\impl\windows\adjust_get_current_system_volume_vista_plus.exe`

Answer (score 0):

to resolve my problem, I needed to include some workarounds on my code.:

1 - I replaced `loudness` package by [`mwl-loudness`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mwl-loudness)

> A node.js library to control the systems output volume fork from
>   https://github.com/LinusU/node-loudness. added hazardous package for
>   electron, fixed that the electron app can't find the correct path
>   which in the "app.asar.unpacked" folder.

2 - I included a alias to the `loudness` package

```
module.exports = {
  resolve: {
    alias: {
      loudness$: 'mwl-loudness/index.js'
    }
  }
};
```

3 - After pack the files, I copied `adjust_get_current_system_volume_vista_plus.exe` to `app.asar.unpacked` directory.

```
afterPack: async function (context) {
  var fs = require('fs')
  var path = require('path')
  var origin = path.join(context.appOutDir, 'resources/app.asar.unpacked/node_modules/mwl-loudness/impl/windows/adjust_get_current_system_volume_vista_plus.exe')
  var destiny = path.join(context.appOutDir, 'resources/app.asar.unpacked/adjust_get_current_system_volume_vista_plus.exe')
  fs.copyFile(origem, destiny, console.log)
}
```